# My 3D UMAP plot is not generating. No errors occurring, just a blank space

Tags: python, plot

Trying to display a 3D plot generated with UMAP and plotly.express (px). here's my code:
data_norm is a numpy array. This code generates a blank space in jupyter notebook. The 2d version of this displays a plot though. This exact code worked in another jupyter notebook (same computer) but with 8 features instead of 8000 that I have now.

```
umap_3d = umap.UMAP(n_components=3, init='random', random_state=0)
proj_3d = umap_3d.fit_transform(data_norm)

fig_3d = px.scatter_3d(
    proj_3d, x=0, y=1, z=2,
    color=df["cluster #"].astype(str), labels={'color': 'cluster #'}
)

fig_3d.update_traces(marker_size=20)

fig_3d.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

FIGURED IT OUT, add this line:

```
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```